CoreWCF: 404 when publishing simple app to Azure
I've created a simple CoreWCF API, following this tutorial.
Here's the contents of Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    options.ListenLocalhost(8080);
});

builder.Services.AddServiceModelWebServices();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
{
    builder.AddService<Service>();
    builder.AddServiceWebEndpoint<Service, IService>("api");
});

app.Run();

And here's the service class:
using CoreWCF.Web;

namespace Test
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/hello")]
        string PathEcho();
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string PathEcho() => "Hello World!";
    }
}

I get a response from the endpoint when I run the app locally. But when I publish the app to an Azure Windows App Service and call the endpoint, I get a 404 error.
https://[app name].azurewebsites.net/api/hello
